# Datatables - 3 fixed columns, 1 responsive

Tags: javascript, css, datatable

Using jQuery DataTables, I've got a simple table with 4 columns. Columns 1 (ID), 3 (Who) and 4 (Status) are are fixed width in px.

```
    $('#tdt').dataTable( {
      "aaData" : tdl,
      "aoColumns" : [
        { "sTitle" : "ID" , "sWidth" : "60px"},
        { "sTitle" : "What"},
        { "sTitle" : "Who", "sWidth" : "80px" },
        { "sTitle" : "Status", "sWidth" : "150px" }
      ],
    });
```

I'd like column 2 to fill the remaining width of the container, and be responsive. So, if the screen size is smaller, columns 1, 3 and 4 stay at their fixed width, but column 2 can become thinner to compensate.

Now if I don't set a width for any of the columns, dataTables is responsive in that it auto-widths all 4 columns, and (as long as the table and the container have width="100%" then the whole thing is responsive.

- http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html demonstrates.

As soon as you set a width for any column, this stops being the case.

Any ideas / solutions for this please? Thanks

Comment: Very hard to get some ideas without any kind of example or code demonstrating what you mean :) I mean, hard to visualize a sentence like "_..that looks very strange as the ID column which just has a number in is extremely wide_" :)

Comment: Maybe use a code bin such as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to create an example test-case?

Comment: Edited to hopefully explain better.

Comment: So what my research is suggesting is that this can't actually be done. Either you don't set any column widths in which case whole table is responsive, or you set 1 or more and then there's no responsiveness. Very surprising this isn't some thing that has been changed / addressed - can't believe I'm the first in this situation!

Comment: **1** don't set the widths in **px**. Use standard responsive units like **%** instead. **2** see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587810/jquery-datatable-to-responsive-data-tables **3** create a [**runnable** test case](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12899/post-test-cases-when-asking-for-help-please-read) **4** open issue at the [DataTables forums](http://datatables.net/forums/) if you don't find answer already there

Answer (score 0):

1 column fixed, 3 columns resonsive...

```
"aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "No"},
            { "mData": "Type_Document" },
            { "mData": "Buy_From_Customer_No" },
            {
                mData: "Buy_From_Customer_Name",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<div style="width:200px;">' + data + '</div>';
                }
            },
```