# Jquery Datatable to responsive data tables

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, datatables, media-queries

I am new to data tables and never created a responsive data tables. So i may be asking much help.

Here is [link](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customization.html) for JQuery data tables editables. I want to create it responsive. First thing i did i removed its container width now its resizing to tablet size screen and looks ok.

```
#fw_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    padding-top: 2em;
}
.full_width {
    width: 90%;
}
```

But on the screen size below than that tables are messing up.

I want data table to work like [this](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/tables/movie-list.html).

I can't give you my site link where i have actually implemented because its in site admin panel.

Any thoughts/helpful links or direction will be helpful to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i suggest you to use responsive data tables... instead of converting it to responsive...

Comment: @AamirShahzad i have already implemented those now no turn around... only solution is to convert to responsive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In responsive design most of the tricks done by percentage values until a certain point and after that we start using @media queries.

For your example just percentages used for the th and td tag I belive you can manage it but if it is smaller than 40em then completely different CSS take control like below;

```
//when width less than 40em you can also use px
@media (max-width: 40em)
{
   // show every item as a line
   .movie-list td, .movie-list th {
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
  }
    //for th and .titles display them as a big bold title with different background color
    .movie-list tbody th, .movie-list tbody td.title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 110%;
    padding: .5em .5em;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #77bbff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }

    //for th only this is only for margin to override previous css
    .movie-list tbody th {
       margin-top: 0;
       text-align: left;
     }
}
```

hope this help this is just give some start;

here your fish mate :) just use developer tool bar and add the code under the h2 Live Example tag;

```
<style>
// check if it is a small device ipad iphone android etc.
// google for example 'css  media queries for mobile"
@media (max-width: 40em) {
  // just did something to display second row use your skills
  table#example tr.even
  {
     border: 2px solid red;
  }  
// exactly the same with other one to display td as rows
// with css selector you can hide first one display 2nd one like a title etc
table#example tr td 
  {
  background-color:white;
     width: 90%;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
  }  
  // remove the thead as we dont need it
  // you should do similar to the footer as well
  table#example thead
  {
     display:none;
  }  
  // hide unwanted pagination elements
  table#example ~ div.fg-toolbar div#example_info, 
    table#example ~ div.fg-toolbar div a
  {
  display:none;
  }
  // and only display next and prev
  // it s not what I actually wanted to make it more tab able make it bigger and try to cover half of the row.  
  table#example ~ div.fg-toolbar div a#example_previous,
  table#example ~ div.fg-toolbar div a#example_next
  {
  display:inline-block;
  width:46% !important;

  }
}

</style>
```

As far as I can tell the edit and add stuffs are working as this is completely css just you have to dig deeper.

Comment: thanks @onur i have familiar with media queries - but issue is how to i re-oganize (break) datatable like this http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/tables/movie-list.html for mobile screen & other small screens

Comment: @Firebug well can you provide some actual code from your solution so we find the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery only. fnAdjustColumnSizing function automatically adjust the with of the headers. When you resize the window we use this funtion.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   //Redraw datable
   $('#your-table').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();//Automatically sets header size
});
```